Do all instances of a given string get replaced under a rewrite rule?
I am doing a course in uni on Automata and Formal Languages, and I think I've come across a pretty significant misunderstanding. When you have a rewrite rule in a grammar, and apply it to a string, do all occurrences of the string on the LHS get rewritten?
For example, if I have the string $abbababc$ over alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$, and rewrite rule $a \to b$ the string $bbbbbbbc$, or could we have also $bbababc$ and $bbbbbabc$, etc.
I thought it was the case that we could have only the first option but reading this answer:
CFG of all regular expressions over a binary alphabet
has made me think maybe differently.

Probably your course teaches the context-free grammar. Indeed, in a CFG one position in the string is chosen, and the symbol at that position is rewritten using one of the rewrite rules.
In a CFG the order of rewrites does not matter, the final result will be the same. (Provided the same rule is used at the respective positions, of course.)
Also note that in a CFG we usually distinguish between variables and terminal symbols. The variables can be rewritten, and the terminals appear in the final string.
There are variants of rewriting systems though. One also considers L systems, where all symbols in the string are rewritten at the same time. Those grammars are motivated by biological processes. They define a completely different class of formal languahes than those defined by context-free grammars.

Cheers. I have no clue how I have gone so long without realising this.

Rewriting systems usually apply each rule once, sequentially. The left hand side might match at several points, in which case any match could be taken,
